# Modifying my javaScript regex to accept forward slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I took a regex for evaluating urls which works nicely but I want to use it to evaluate facebook accounts. For example www.facebook.com/myname.

How this regex doesn't like the forward slash after .com.

```
.directive('validateTheUrl', function() {
                // hey chaps this is the new ng 1.3 way to custom validtae stuff..... 

                    var REQUIRED_PATTERNS = [/^(?:(ftp|http|https)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){2,6}$/];

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators.theUrl = function (value) {
                    var status = true;
                    angular.forEach(REQUIRED_PATTERNS, function (pattern) {
                        status = status && pattern.test(value);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                    return status;
                };
            }
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know how I would update the regex?

Comment: If you just want to match facebook account, why don't you use `www\.facebook\.com/[\w]+`

Comment: Try escaping the \ using a \ .. I think escaping will work

Comment: Let see, but look for https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simply append to the regex pattern to accept a forward slash after the .com

```
[/^(?:(ftp|http|https)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){2,6}\/[\w-]+$/];
```